# Scenarios for On-Device Speech-to-Text Support

Tags: cobalt

```
// Whether the current platform has microphone supported.
#define SB_HAS_MICROPHONE 0
// Whether the current platform has speech recognizer.
#define SB_HAS_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER 0
// Whether the current platform has speech synthesis.
#define SB_HAS_SPEECH_SYNTHESIS 0
```

I'm curious about #define for these.

1. YouTube search box
2. Speak the video you want on the microphone
3. Search video
4. Ouput video thumbnail after voice data analysis

Is it implemented in this way?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to YouTube search page
2. Speak out the search key word
3. Voice recognition system recognizes the voice and returns it as text
4. Search video by the text and show thumbnails

More details are described in https://sites.google.com/a/google.com/youtube-leanback-partners/integration/voice-search

To **test** the voice search, you should use the following parameter. This parameter should not be used in the product though.
https://www.youtube.com/tv?env_supportsVoiceSearch=1
To launch voice search in the product, work with your technical PoC.